# Deny ftp users when they try to log in with sftp or ssh

Tags: ssh, centos7, ftp, sftp

I want my FTP users on Centos 7 to not be able to connect via ssh or ftp. I saw someone using “Password denied” when they try to log in with ssh, but I want to let only 1 ip to be able to access ssh, and ftp users when they try to, to show them “password incorrect” even if password is correct for ftp.

Comment: Sorry for mistake “via ssh or sftp*”

Comment: Most ftp servers supports using a different password database than the default pam, I would suggest you to use a totally different one for ftp, so that ftp users can never login because they dont have a password in the regular system password file.

Comment: It might also be possible to do this with pam.d modules, but I'm not skilled enough to propose a solution there.